# Assign testers to test and define build in rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-pipelines

We are developing a robotics product that requires quite a few manual tests in every release cycle and we want to automate the management of these tests.

We envision a process with these steps:

- One or more test plans are assigned to one or more testers by new stage in our release pipeline using the Azure DevOps REST API (with the respective build artifact related to the pipeline)
- Manual testing takes place
- A deployment gate keeps the release in a testing stage until all tests have passed (solvable with a function app that parses the response from: `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?buildUri={buildUri}`

Is it possible to assign testers (to test a specific build) using the REST API [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to assign testers (to test a specific build) using the
> REST API

The answer is yes. You can use [Test Point - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test%20point/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api to achieve this.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/TestPoint?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

Update Test Points. This is used to Reset test point to active, update the outcome of a test point or update the tester of a test point.